# How to get plt.imshow to display negative coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, homography

I have a task of stitching two images into panorama picture using linear algebra. One of the images that gets transformed has most of its contents in coordinates that are equal less than 0, so imshow doesn't show them for me.
[image]

Is there any way to either show negative values of image, expanding the plot, or at least to move who image to the right in order to show more of it?

I tried using expand and origin, but just couldn't get it to work properly, as I don't have much knowledge about this subject.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img1 = Image.open("gwint1.png")
coeffs=np.array([0.207879489,0.1122809023,496.629559,-0.341172122,0.908759060,53.1000028&,-0.000964805704,0.000223378490]).reshape(4,2)
plt.imshow(img1.transform((width,height),Image.PERSPECTIVE, coeffs, fill=0, fillcolor='black'),alpha=1);
```

Comment: Please could you [edit] your question include your code, as text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is lacking reproducible code and data. `imshow()` doesn't have problems with negative coordinates (given via `extent=...`). What can be unexpected, however, is that when you call `imshow()` a second time, the plot limits are automatically set adjusted to the limits of the second image. You explicitly need to call `plt.xlim(...)` and `plt.ylim(...)` with the full range (to be called after the last `imshow()`).

Comment: half of the picture *is* black, the x-positive side.